# How to handle unwrapped function return to avoid crash app

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have a function `generate(...)` (external library) that returns `String!`. Sometimes it crashes for some reason on this line:

`let token = self.otp.generate(accountId, secpin: newpin, props: props)`

All parameters are validated before call this function.

I tried to handle `with do-try-catch`and `if let` but with no success because this function "always" return an unwrapped value and it is not possible using with `try` or `try?` in a `do-try-catch` block.

I would like to handle this exception and not crash the app.

Comment: You cannot handle an exception using Swift error handling. An exception is an NSException, not a thrown Error. You need to tell us more about the crash. What crashes and why? Show the error message and backtrace.

Comment: If the function is not declared to throw then you can't use `try`

Comment: I never reproduced this error no my machine. I received this error from Crashes on organizer in XCode, and I have no good debug information about, only the line with error. The support team received a call about a crash on this screen, then I would like to prevent crash on this part of app.

Comment: An unwrapped optional is still an optional. You can prevent a crash with `if/guard let`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an optional `token` variable and assign the result of generate to that.

```
let token: String? = self.otp.generate(accountId, secpin: newpin, props: props)
```

Then, you can evaluate the value optionality with an `if let` or a `guard` statement.

```
if let token: String = token {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The crash happens inside `generate` so this will not change anything

Comment: In that case yes, there's nothing you can do unless you can change whats inside.